# python's paramiko load_system_host_keys() throwing AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'value' (cryptography)

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

This issue is appearing in paramiko v2 (2.4.2) and not in paramiko v1 (1.18.5).

Keys are stored in the known_hosts file.

I'm using the following code

```
import paramiko

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.load_system_host_keys()
ssh_client.connect(hostname='hostname', username='user', password='pass')
```

load_system_host_keys() fails and I'm getting this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/85/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1664, in <module>
    main()
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/85/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1658, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/85/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1068, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/home/administrator/rs_autolabs/utils/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    ssh_client.load_system_host_keys()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 104, in load_system_host_keys
    self._system_host_keys.load(filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/hostkeys.py", line 97, in load
    e = HostKeyEntry.from_line(line, lineno)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/hostkeys.py", line 356, in from_line
    key = RSAKey(data=decodebytes(key))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 69, in __init__
    ).public_key(default_backend())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py", line 15, in default_backend
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 16, in <module>
    from cryptography import utils, x509
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.base import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/base.py", line 16, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.extensions import Extension, ExtensionType
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/extensions.py", line 24, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.general_name import GeneralName, IPAddress, OtherName
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/general_name.py", line 18, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.name import Name
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/name.py", line 28, in <module>
    _ASN1_TYPE_TO_ENUM = dict((i.value, i) for i in _ASN1Type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/name.py", line 28, in <genexpr>
    _ASN1_TYPE_TO_ENUM = dict((i.value, i) for i in _ASN1Type)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Comment: Did you try to find out, what specific host key is causing the problem?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I currently have only one key in the known_hosts file just for testing. I've used: ssh-keyscan -H my_hostname >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts to add it.
I have another scenario where paramiko.AutoAddPolicy() added a lot of hosts to the known_hosts file and I think I saw this error with every host I've tried to connect to.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I've also tried to add the key just by connecting to the host and answering 'yes' to 'The authenticity of host can't be established'. After that I have only one key and I get the same error.

Comment: OK, than it looks like your Python installation is somehow broken (or your installation of OpenSSL package).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl  when following paramiko files on debug the problem is with:         'from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend'
I'll try to use https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/ to see if I'm missing something

Answer (score 0):

The solution is an issue with the enum module.
cryptography uses enum34.
I had my own implementation to enum in 'enum.py' file that was in the same package of my code.
cryptography tried to use this module instead of enum34.
reaming my 'enum.py' file to something else solved it.

read here:
[python's cryptography throwing AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'value'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52810552/pythons-cryptography-throwing-attributeerror-int-object-has-no-attribute-va/52810764#52810764)