# python's cryptography throwing AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'value'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, cryptography

I'm trying to execute the following code:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
key = Fernet.generate_key()
cipher_suite = Fernet(key)
cipher_text = cipher_suite.encrypt(b"A really secret message. Not for prying eyes.")
plain_text = cipher_suite.decrypt(cipher_text)
print plain_text
```

Getting:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe E:/PycharmProjects/my_project/utils/encryption.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/PycharmProjects/my_project/utils/encryption.py", line 3, in <module>
    cipher_suite = Fernet(key)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 32, in __init__
    backend = default_backend()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\__init__.py", line 15, in default_backend
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\backend.py", line 16, in <module>
    from cryptography import utils, x509
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\x509\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.base import (
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\x509\base.py", line 16, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.extensions import Extension, ExtensionType
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\x509\extensions.py", line 24, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.general_name import GeneralName, IPAddress, OtherName
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\x509\general_name.py", line 18, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.name import Name
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\x509\name.py", line 28, in <module>
    _ASN1_TYPE_TO_ENUM = dict((i.value, i) for i in _ASN1Type)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\x509\name.py", line 28, in <genexpr>
    _ASN1_TYPE_TO_ENUM = dict((i.value, i) for i in _ASN1Type)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'value'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The file path is: my_project/utils/encryption.py

Running the same code outside the 'utils' package or in python console works fine.
What could be the issue?

Comment: when it works fine, have you checked python version?

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.13. To make it works I just moving the file from root/utils/file.py to root/file.py and it works!

Answer (score 2):

The cryptography code needs the Python 3 enum: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34 . That is why you got that issue.

I suggest to verify if your version is right and not replaced by another module as well.

Comment: "Let me know if you have any other question." you should probably edit that out. Stackoverflow is a Q&A site, not a regular forum (as you probably know since you're quite experienced here). That seems to be the correct answer, but maybe you could elaborate more. Looks very much like a "comment-like answer". Pity.

Comment: @Jonathan Gagne - I have enum34 installed already. Also tried to re-install it. still not working.

Comment: Something that could be related: I have a module 'enum.py' in my 'utils' package. This is a module I implemented myself and not enum34.
Could be cryptography is trying to use this instead of enum34 ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had a module named enum.py along with the cryptography code (same package). cryptography tried to use it instead of enum34.
Renaming the 'enum.py' to something else solved it.